# How to disable Wii updates through router filtering?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

Since there is no way to disable Wii updates through the device itself, I was wondering if anybody knows what IP (or any other identifiable information) the Wii updates come from?

I was thinking that if someone knew what the traffic looks like before or during a Wii update, I could create a filter in my router to block those communications to my Wii.

Comment: Updates are optional and not automatic, so this should not really be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution for you will be to give your Wii a static ip-address, then, at the router, simply block all traffic to-and-from the Wii.

Of course, this will eliminate all internet access from the console, but I'm quite sure that all of that content is inaccessible anyway if your system isn't up to date.

Comment: If the idea were to completely block access, it'd be simpler just to clear the wireless setup on the Wii itself.

Comment: I agree with Dave.